# AWS IPV6 Support

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, facebook-javascript-sdk, amazon-elb

I'm having issues with facebook scraping my pages. The Facebook Debugger is giving me a 504 Timeout. I starting to think it's because of IPv6 support on my EC2 instance.

I'm in the process of setting up a ELB to test this out.

Anybody have an issue with this. It used to work just fine but you know how the cloud can change on you.

Is the ELB the only support for IPv6? What about API Gateway?

Lastly, the practice has been to terminate SSL/TLS at the ELB and rely on private internal networks in AWS to protect your data from the ELB to the EC2 instance.

Can I rely on AWS to get my traffic to my EC2 instance and back without a sniffer picking off my sensitive data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately as of yet, EC2 doesn't support IPv6. API Gateway can't help you here. The IPv6 support for ELB is really designed as a workaround. See the [forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=536049) for more info.

With regards to your packets being sniffed, I think you don't need to worry about it. Once your packets are being routed inside your VPC they can't be sniffed from the outside or by any other VPC user. I'm sure if some engineer at AWS really wanted to (as they own the infrastructure), they could sniff your packets, but it would operate outside the assurances of security and privacy they advertise. I think it's ok not to worry about encrypting packets once inside your VPC, and I believe most VPC users (including myself) do not go to these lengths.

Answer (score 1):

This [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zd5hsL-JNY4&feature=youtu.be) from re:Invent 2013 describes VPCs and how packets are routed in and between subnets. Particular details at 24 minute mark. Bottom line: you don't need to worry about a third party sniffing your packets. 
From the description, packets are verified at both the sender and the receiver, so even if the fabric fails and sends your packet to someone else's instance, the low-level driver on that instance will refuse to accept the packet (and it will trigger an alarm).

Can Amazon sniff your packets? In theory a rogue employee could, but can they do it and get away with it, Amazon claims no. But if Amazon is considered a threat then they could pull packets out of memory or even pull any TLS keys out of memory, since they own the hypervisor... You either trust Amazon or you don't use EC2. There's no middle ground there.